# Evaluating integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Math question please take a look at the picture,
Evalulate the $$\int_{\Gamma} z^2\:dz$$ where $\Gamma$ is the parabola arc $$y=x^2$$ running from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$.

when I look at the solution, I don't understand how $$z^2 = x^2+x^4$$
shouldn't it be $$x^2+2ix^3-x^4$$????

[image: Math question please take a look at the picture]

[image: 1solution]

Comment: the bracketed 10 points first seemed to me as a small bounty  via a up-vote to good answer

Comment: The solution posted here has a serious problem.  Do you see it?

Comment: Looks to me like there might be a small notational issue - I suspect that, when it says $z^2$, it means $|z|^2$.

Comment: The poser of the problem could have intended that.  But that is not what the problem says.  Fail.

Comment: @GlenO I'd agree with that. It is quite noticeable that the space between the $z$ and the $2$ in $z^2$ is much larger than the corresponding space e.g. in $x^2$. Probably the vertical bars just got lost due to  the bad scanning resolution.

Comment: One more point: if $z^2$ was really meant instead of $|z|^2$, then there would be no point going along the parabola, as the integral is then path independent.

Comment: @ElmarZander: why?  I don't think $|z|^2$ is analytic in a region containing the path. $z^2$, on the other hand, is.

Comment: @RonGordon Yes, that's the point. $z^2$ is holomorphic on the whole complex plane, so the value of the integral would only depend on the endpoints, and you could just as well go on a straight line from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$.

Comment: @ElmarZander: sorry, I read you backwards.  My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parametrize the contour as follows: $x=t$, $y=t^2$, $t \in [0,1]$.  Then $z=t+i t^2$, $dz=(1+i 2 t) dt$ on the contour.  The integral then becomes

$$\int_0^1 dt\: (1+i 2 t) (t+i t^2)^2$$

You should be able to do this.

I should point out that this integral is path independent because $z^2$ is analytic in a region surrounding the endpoints.  You can see this by evaluating

$$\int_0^{1+i} dz \: z^2 = \frac{1}{3} (1+i)^3 = \frac{1}{3} (1+3 i-3-i) = \frac{2}{3} (-1+i)$$

Comment: Hi Ron, Thank you so much for the answer. 
I tried your method and I got 1/2i-4/5. I am really confused because it doesn't match with the solution I have. Is the solution wrong or am I doing something weird here.

Comment: I get $-2/3+i 2/3 = (2/3) (-1+i)$.

Comment: yes right, sorry I got that too. But please take a look at the solution I posted. Is the solution wrong?

Comment: That solution has a serious problem.  You should be able to spot it.  If not, let me know.